# How to configure partial replication of Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, replication, oracle-11g, archive

Suppose we have 2 identical **Oracle 11g** DB schemas: `PRODUCTION` and `ARCHIVE`.

The goal is to keep in `PRODUCTION` the minimal amount of data required for online operations,
and use `ARCHIVE` to store all the data ever appeared in `PRODUCTION` to build reports.

To be clear:

1. we define ***"obsolete data"*** using some custom rules
2. ***"active data"*** is all the data except for ***"obsolete data"***
3. `ARCHIVE` should be populated by ***"active data"*** from `PRODUCTION` by schedule (for example every midnight or every week)
4. any new ***"obsolete data"*** should be removed from `PRODUCTION` but remained in `ARCHIVE`

I believe all these points could be satisfied by independently running:

- Uni-directional replication (for instance, Oracle Streams)
- application for "Obsolete data" removal (suppose it is implemented)

But the problem is that any `Obsolete data removing application` implicitly produces REDO logs in `PRODUCTION` which are going to be propagated to `ARCHIVE` and hence this process leads to data loss in `ARCHIVE`.

Could you give an advice, how to organize the process of "partial replication",
which could ignore some specific deletions in master schema.

Comment: Your archive is more a data warehouse than a replica/stand by.  Look for information about ETL, you will find plenty of help online.

Comment: you have two schemas, but are they in the same or in different databases?

Comment: Agreed with @GerardH.Pille look up ETL methodologies.  You can choose a product like Informatica or DataStage, or you can design your own with something like MERGE (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm)

Comment: @miracle173 in general, they could be in two different DBs